# Rust bindgen: Generate functions with hidden visibility

Tags: c, rust, bindgen

I'm using rust-bindgen to generate rust bindings for a C library that I want to link statically. The Library uses __attribute((visibility("hidden"))) on some functions that should not be accessible on shared libraries.

Unfortunately rust-bindgen does not generate functions, that have this attribute set:

`cat header.h`

```c
__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) void f_hidden();
__attribute__((visibility("default"))) void f_default();
```

`bindgen header.h`

```rust
/* automatically generated by rust-bindgen 0.66.1 */

extern "C" {
    pub fn f_default();
}
```

How can I tell bindgen to generate hidden functions too? - The library will be statically linked anyway, so the functions will be accessible.

I am not able to change the C headers, as they are not part of the project.

Comment: as a workaround: adding `-D"__attribute__(x)="` to the cflags helps here, but this may have side effects.

Comment: In a similar vein, you could alternatively add `-fvisibility=default` to the args that bindgen passes to clang.

Comment: That doesn't have any effect as the command line argument overwrites the default visibility only. The actual visibility set by `__attribute__()` takes precedence.

Comment: Visibility annotations can be used for optimization, so the functions may not be present in the binary. That said, unless something like `-D"visbility(x)="` works, you'll need to pre-process the header file.